# Bulk Insert csv file error

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulk-insert

I am trying to [`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) a csv file to my SQL Server.

Using code I found on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076309/import-multiple-csv-files-to-sql-server-from-a-folder), I ran:

```
BULK INSERT Temp 
FROM 'c:\csv\student.csv '  
WITH ( 
       FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
       ROWTERMINATOR   = '\n', 
       FIRSTROW        = 2 
     )
```

I got this error:

> Msg 208 , Level 16 , state 82 , Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'Temp' .

What can I do?

Answer (score 6):

Your error message means the object can't be found in the context of the session where you're executing your `BULK INSERT`. This could be because...

1. The object does not exist and needs to be created. Try `CREATE TABLE [Temp] ( ...`

   - Also check for typos, did you mean to insert into `Temp2` instead?
   - You may need to specify the schema name. Are you trying to insert into `foo.Temp` instead of `dbo.Temp`?
2. You are connected to the wrong database **OR** server **OR** are using the wrong credentials.

   - Do you get the same error message when you run `select top(1) * from [Temp];` ***In the same session where you got the error message the first time?***

Other reading:

- [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3069356/4709762)
- [tsql.info](https://www.tsql.info/error/msg-208-level-16-invalid-object-name.php)
- [experts-exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28404280/Invalid-object-name-when-doing-a-bulk-insert.html)